# Inductive relation for the Harmonic series

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

Let's consider the serie
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} = \frac{s_n}{t_n}$$
where $ s_n$ and $t_n $ are coprime. Is there a way to find an inductive relation between $ s_n,t_n, s_{n+1}, t_{n+1}$?

We know that
$$ S = \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{k} - \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} = \frac{(n+1)s_n+t_n}{t_n(n+1)}  $$ The only problem left is to show that the numerator and denominator of this expression $S$ are coprime.

Comment: And why do we believe that they are coprime? (Offhand, I don't.)  Have you made any examples?

Comment: Your sum is not defined because it contains $\dfrac{1}{0}$.

Comment: That approach already fails at $n=3$: $1+1/2+1/3 = 11/6$, then $11/6 + 1/4 = 50/24 = 25/12$.

Comment: Yes, thank you this approach seems false.Yet, can we determine a relation between those 4 integers? A simplification perhaps ?

Comment: This is actually an exercise i've been given.We eventually need to write an algorithm that returns both the denominator and numerator based on this supposedly inductive formula that we are going to find.